# subset types, refinement types, proof relevance and equality

Tags: coq

I am not too sure which title I should use for this question. If anyone understands the issue raised here, please feel free to provide a better title.

I have defined a type which is meant to model the structure of category on a type `A`. The instances of `A` represent the arrows while an instance of `Category A` represents the operations available on these arrows as well as the proofs which provide guarantees that the category laws are satisfied. This point of view effectively identifies objects with their corresponding identity arrows.

```
Record Category (A:Type) : Type := category
    { source    : A -> A
    ; target    : A -> A
    ; compose   : A -> A -> option A
    ; proof_ss  : forall f:A,      source (source f) = source f    
    ; proof_ts  : forall f:A,      target (source f) = source f
    ; proof_tt  : forall f:A,      target (target f) = target f
    ; proof_st  : forall f:A,      source (target f) = target f
    ; proof_dom : forall f g:A,    target f = source g <-> compose f g <> None
    ; proof_src : forall f g h:A,  compose f g = Some h -> source h = source f
    ; proof_tgt : forall f g h:A,  compose f g = Some h -> target h = target g
    ; proof_idl : forall a f:A,    a = source f -> compose a f = Some f
    ; proof_idr : forall a f:A,    a = target f -> compose f a = Some f
    ; proof_asc : forall f g h fg gh:A, compose f g = Some fg -> 
                                        compose g h = Some gh -> 
                                        compose f gh = compose fg h
    }
    .
```

Now a more traditional point of view is one which actually distinguishes between objects and arrows, and considers two separate classes (sets, types) for them. So I also defined:

```
Record Category2 (Obj Mor:Type) : Type := category2
    { dom       : Mor -> Obj
    ; cod       : Mor -> Obj
    ; compose2  : Mor -> Mor -> option Mor
    ; id        : Obj -> Mor
    ; proof_sid : forall a:Obj, dom (id a) = a
    ; proof_tid : forall a:Obj, cod (id a) = a
    ; proof_dom2: forall f g:Mor, cod f = dom g <-> compose2 f g <> None
    ; proof_src2: forall f g h: Mor, compose2 f g = Some h -> dom h = dom f
    ; proof_tgt2: forall f g h: Mor, compose2 f g = Some h -> cod h = cod g
    ; proof_idl2: forall (a:Obj) (f:Mor), a = dom f -> compose2 (id a) f = Some f
    ; proof_idr2: forall (a:Obj) (f:Mor), a = cod f -> compose2 f (id a) = Some f
    ; proof_asc2: forall f g h fg gh: Mor,    compose2 f g = Some fg ->
                                              compose2 g h = Some gh ->
                                              compose2 f gh = compose2 fg h
    }
    .
```

Now of course, one would like to check that these two points of views are equivalent in some way. So we would like to write a function:

```
Definition toCategory (Obj Mor:Type) (c:Category2 Obj Mor) : Category Mor := ...
```

which given a structure of type `Category2` returns a structure of type `Category`. This function is not very hard to write. However, we would also like to go the other way, and here we have an immediate challenge: Given a structure of type `Category A`, before we can hope to define a structure of type `Category2` we need to choose some underlying types `Obj` and `Mor`. It is very natural to pick `Mor = A` and I initially decided upon:

```
Definition Obj (A:Type) (c:Category A) : Type := { a:A | source c a = a }.
```

The predicate `fun (x:A) => source c x = x` effectively singles out those arrows which are fixed point of the `source` operator, i.e. those arrows which are identity arrows, i.e. those arrows which can be viewed as objects.

The problem with this definition is that in order to construct an instance of type `Category2 Obj Mor` I need to provide proofs of equality between objects such as `dom (id a) = a`. These objects being`sig` types are effectively triples containing the predicate, the value, and the proof that the value satisfies the predicate, and attempting to prove equality between these things doesn't seems to lead me anywhere. So given my current knowledge of `Coq` I am stuck in my design, and would welcome any suggestion.

Comment: To all purposes, you want to become _irrelevant_ on the proofs used. This can be achieved in many ways; I'd suggest that for prototyping purposes you use the "proof irrelevance" axiom.

Comment: @ejgallego Thank you very much, I will look this up.